# Finding max value in a array

Tags: c++

I'm doing a program that finds the max value in a array. I done it but I found a strange bug.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n; //input number of elements in 
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i]; //input array's elements
    } int max_value = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max_value) {
            max_value = arr[i];
        }
    } cout << max_value;
    return 0;
}
```

When I put 5 as first line for the number of elements and 2, 7, 6, 8, 9 as the elements of the array. It returns 16 instead of 9. Please help

Comment: Arrays in C++ start at 0, not 1. You're iterating to one-past-the-end, which is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: Variable length arrays are not standard C++ so this code is not portable. Whitespace is free, you should consider using some. Things like `} int max_value = arr[0];` give me a headache.

Comment: See also [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Arrays the first index starts with `0` and ends in `n - 1` assuming the array is of length `n`

so when looping from `i = 1` to `i <= n`. n is now larger than `n - 1`.
the solution would be to start from `0` and end at `i < n` hence:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n; //input number of elements in 
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i]; //input array's elements
    } int max_value = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max_value) {
            max_value = arr[i];
        }
    }
    cout << max_value;
    return 0;
}
```

you could also use the `std::max` function like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
   max_value = max(max_value, arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Worth also noting comments 2 and 3 under the main question in your answer. `int arr[n];` with `int n;` isn't valid C++, it's a non-standard extension.

Answer (score 1):

in your second for do this

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > max_value) {
        max_value = arr[i];
    }
```

delete '=' from i <= n because i is index which start from 0

and instead of this

```
int arr[n];
```

do this

```
int *arr = new int[n];
```

Comment: `int arr* = new int[n];` statement is not valid, it should be `int *arr = new int[n];`.

Comment: And better use `std::vector` in this case. It can be accessed like an array, if you do not like `push_back`. If you insist on C arrays, use `make_unique` in its array form.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The other posts already pointed out problem in your code.

You should be aware of that `int arr[n];` is not permitted in standard C++.
*[[GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) and [CLANG](https://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla) compiler support it in C++ as an extension]*

An alternative is to allocate memory dynamically:

```
    int *arr = new int[n];
```

and to find maximum value you can use `std::max_element`:

```
    int max_value = *(std::max_element(arr, arr + n));
```

Instead of dynamic array, its better to use `vector` STL (make yourself familiar with [Containers Library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)). You can do:

```
    std::vector <int> arr;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int input;
        std::cin >> input;
        arr.push_back(input);
    } 

    int max_value = *std::max_element(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    std::cout << "Max element is :" << max_value << std::endl;
```